# Transpose Column to other Columns in Batches of 1000 in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet where I'm pasting 7000 rows data into column A1.

When the data his `A1000`, I want the next 1000 rows to go to column B, populating cells `B1:B1000`. I want next 1000 to go to column C, populating cells `C1:C1000`, etc.

Ideally, I would like this to happen via a formula. I do not want to use any of the manual commands (i.e. Transpose, etc.)

*I have looked through similar questions, and haven't found one that answers my question specifically -- thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(ROW()>1000,"",IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,ROW()+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*1000),""))
```

Sheet1!$A:$A is your Data in sheet1
In another sheet write the above formula in A1 and drag it **in column and in row**

[image]

Comment: The IFERROR seems a little redundant; I cannot see any way that the INDEX will return a #N/A but it *may* return a *0* instead of a blank cell.

Comment: It did cut off at 1000, but I wanted cell A1001 in the Data Sheet to start populating Cells B1:B1000 in my other sheet. Once B1000 was populated, I want it to start populating C1:C1000. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just drag the formula in the first row horizontally

Comment: You rule! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a worksheet's code sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Const iMAX As Long = 5

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim r As Long
        For r = iMAX + 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Step iMAX
            With Cells(r, "A").Resize(iMAX, 1)
                Debug.Print .Address
                .TextToColumns Destination:=.Parent.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, r / iMAX), _
                               DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
                .Clear
            End With
        Next r
    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.